# Подуспокоившись

Tags: общие-вопросы

Всегда казалось, что есть такое слово. По крайней мере, приходилось слышать. Ввёл в поисковик — а он настаивает на "поуспокоившись" (без "д"). Так как верно-то? Есть ли вообще такие слова?

Comment: Любопытно, что гугл на запрос "поуспокоился" (я ниже в комментарии назвал слово в этой форме странным) предлагает искать тексты с "подуспокоился". Надо бы посмотреть сравнительную частотность, но пока сервисы попадаются с регистрацией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С гуглом не вижу такого глюка. В книгах, прошедших корректуру, это слово не раз встречается; словообразование нормальное (подустал, подуспокоился и т. п.) - о малой степени или начальной стадии успокоения. "Поуспокоиться" может относиться к множественным лицам (все они попадали, но, встав, все поуспокоились - что скопом не поумирают) - о действии, повально распространившемся на многих. Эти два слова не взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: _...(подустал, подуспокоился и т. п.) - о малой степени или начальной стадии успокоения_. === Так и у слова _поуспокоиться_ такое же значение: _немного, слегка успокоиться_ (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/132321/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F). Почему же тогда Вы считаете, что "эти два слова не взаимозаменяемы"?

Comment: В данном случае я усматриваю при словообразовании через "по-" признак множественности: типичные выражения "страсти поутихли, поуспокоились" воспринимаю нормально, а "он поуспокоился" для меня звучит странно. При образовании некоторых других слов происходит невольный перенос и на единственное число (страсти поутихли -> буря поутихла), но в нашем случае разделение вижу отчётливо - бог с ними, с составителями и обобщителями :)

Comment: Alex_ander *В данном случае я усматриваю при словообразовании через "по-" признак множественности* - есть такое. Но не императивно. "Он попривык (к новым условиям)". Или вот: "подъел и поел". Тут другое, видимо. Он подуспокоился - это четко  достигнутая степень некоторого спокойствия.    А "поуспокоился" - как хочешь, так и трактуй. Может ненадолго успокоился. Или попытался только успокоиться, но не достиг цели. "По" - вообще очень многозначная приставка.